# Using Switch in SSRS

Tags: ssrs

In the below expression I am wanting to evaluate several things. I want to turn the value red if the material % is greater than 89.9 %. If it is not then look at the following. is the invoice amount less than 75 dollars and the material % is greater than 20% then turn orange.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Matl_.Value > 89.9, "RED", Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 75 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 20, "ORANGE", Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 76 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 150 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 30, "ORANGE", Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 151 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 250 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 40, "ORANGE",  Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 226 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 375 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 50, "ORANGE",  Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 376 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 625 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 60, "ORANGE",  Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 626 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 850 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 67.5, "ORANGE",  Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 851 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 1500 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 7500, "ORANGE",  Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 1501 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 2500 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 80, "ORANGE",  Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 3501 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 4500 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 84, "ORANGE",  Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 4501 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 5000 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 85, "ORANGE")
```

The way i have it now looks like it is stopping after looking at just this:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Matl_.Value > 89.9, "RED", Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 75 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 20, "ORANGE"
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Tyler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you read the expression you have written very carefully because your logic is flawed and that is why your `SWITCH` statement is not working as you believe it should.

```
=SWITCH
    (Fields!Matl_.Value > 89.9, "RED", 
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 75 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 20, "ORANGE", 
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 76 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 150 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 30, "ORANGE", 
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 151 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 250 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 40, "ORANGE",  
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 226 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 375 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 50, "ORANGE",  
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 376 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 625 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 60, "ORANGE",  
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 626 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 850 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 67.5, "ORANGE",  
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 851 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 1500 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 7500, "ORANGE",  
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 1501 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 2500 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 80, "ORANGE",  
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 3501 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 4500 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 84, "ORANGE",  
        Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 4501 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 5000 and Fields!Matl_.Value > 85, "ORANGE"
    )
```

When you format the code, it's easy to see you have written clauses like:

```
Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value < 76 and Fields!IHDAR_AMT1.Value > 150
```

The value of `IHDAR_AMT1.Value` cannot be both less than 76 and greater than 150, so it immediately evaluates to `FALSE`.

Comment: Cant believe i didn't catch that. Got so into writing stating missing simple logic! Thanks so much for the help!